# Calculate geom_smooth points without drawing chart

Tags: r, asp.net-mvc, plotly

I am using R language for computing statistical data with MVC web application.

I am using it for generating correlation scatterpoint chart with smoothing line.

My problem is I need only data point values (I am converting data to json and using json for generating chart in my web application using javascript chart library).

So, if I use `ggplot` function with `geom_smooth` then it displays graphics window when I debug my application.

I only want calculated values for X and Y axis.

Is there any way I could calculate only X and Y co-ordinates for showing smooth line in chart?

Comment: You rly don't want to treat R as a magic stats box. The fact that you don't know what statistical transformations `geom_smooth()` is using means you don't even know if what it's doing is the right thing for your data. The man page for `geom_smooth` tells you what stats functions it calls under different data set circumstances, but you should prbly read up quite a bit more on statistics and also the stats side of R before using the magically generated data pairs in any context.

Comment: Yeah I don't know obviously, that's why I asked for help to explain, and that's what the question is about.

Comment: Nope. That is not what the question is abt. Your question is "how do i get the magical points created by the magic function?". Since you only want the  magic points just look at the help for `geom_smooth`. It tells you _exactly_ what function it uses. Or use `ggplot_build()` and examine the resulting data structures. Neither results will improve the veracity of your results, though, since they may not even be the right model for the data you're inputting.

Comment: Okey.. It might be my mistake. Thanks for your guidance, will explore more in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the geom_smooth function will add a regression fitting line to your plot. If you only need the X and Y returned by the regression method, you can use any regression function to compute the model for you then predict based on the original X value.

For example, suppose that loess is the chosen regression function:

```
df.loess <- loess(Y ~ X, df)
points <- data.frame(Y = predict(df.loess, df$X), X = df$X)
```